# How to prove the space $L^2\big([a,b],w(t)\big)$ is complete and separable?

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, hilbert-spaces, complete-spaces, separable-spaces

Suppose $w(t)$ is a positive and measurable function on $[a,b]$. If $x(t)$ is a measurable real function on $[a,b]$ satisfying $$
\left\|  x \right\|^2 =\int\limits_{\left[ a,b \right]}{w\left( t \right) \left| x\left( t\right) \right|}^2dt<+\infty $$
then we say $x(t)$ is a square integrable function with respect to the weight function $w(t)$. We use $L^2\big([a,b];w(t)\big) $ to  represent the set of all square integrable function with respect to the weight function $w(t)$.

I want to show that $L^2\big([a,b];w(t)\big)$ is a Hilbert space: I have already proved it is a normed space, but I don't know how to prove its completeness and separability.

I know how to prove the completeness and separability of $L^2([a,b])$, and I wonder if there is some inequality like the (may be wrong) following one
$$
\int\limits_{\left[ a,b \right]}{\left| x_n\left( t \right) -x_m\left( t \right) \right|}^2dt<\int\limits_{\left[ a,b \right]}{w\left( t \right) dt}\int\limits_{\left[ a,b \right]}{\left| x_n\left( t \right) -x_m\left( t \right) \right|}^2dt
$$
which allows me to use the completeness and separability of $L^2([a,b])$.

Thank you for sharing your ideas.

Comment: The functions $e_n(t) = {1 \over \sqrt{w(t)(b-a)}} e^{i {2n \pi \over b-a}t}$are a complete orthornormal set. Or you could define an isometry between $L^2[a,b]$ and the space above in a similar manner.